# JPanel inside JScrollPane expanding on pack

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) inside of a [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) which is nested inside some other containers. My JPanel uses a modified FlowLayout from SO user [jxd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513838) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4611117/1111886).

This may be information overkill but the full nesting of the panel in question is as follows:

JPanel (ModifiedFlowLayout) > JScrollPane > JPanel (GridBagLayout) > JTabbedPane > JPanel (GridBagLayout) > JSplitPane > JPanel (BorderLayout) > JFrame.

The problem is that when I call [pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) on my JFrame the JScrollPane/JPanel expands horizontally to fill the entire remaining screen space (across multiple monitors). The space used is more than is needed to display all of the components in the JPanel. I tried using [setMaximumSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMaximumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) on my JPanel but it seems to be ignored in this scenario.

Ideally I would like the panel to have it's size dictated by space left after sizing the components that surround it. Can/how can this been done?

Comment: Did you try overriding `getPreferredSize()`?

Comment: @nachokk Well I'll be damned. I thought maximum size would be a more important factor than preferred size but setting that seems to have prevented the expanding although it has caused the ModifiedFlowLayout to start behaving improperly but that may be a different issue. Also I didn't override it since I have only used JPanel not extended it. I used `setPreferedSize()` instead.

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: @nachokk Interesting find that now the panel is still gigantic (this wasn't easily seen given I used `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER`) and mostly empty but it does not expand the entire frame when packed.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred size of a FlowLayout will try to display all components on a single row. I don't know how the ModifiedFlowLayout works but you can check out [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which does the same thing.

However, when using `Wrap Layout` you can use the setSize(...) method to make a suggestion as to what the initial width should be. Initial wrapping of components should then be based on that size.

Comment: I tried it and it seems WrapLayout and ModifiedFlowLayout have the same behavior. @nachokk's comment to use preferred size instead of maximum size turned out to be the solution to the question at hand but he did not post it as an answer thus I cannot mark it.

Comment: @Fr33dan, you should NOT be using setPreferredSize(). The layout will not dynamically change if the user ever resizes the frame.

Comment: That is true if I use `setPreferredSize()` on my JPanel if I do it directly to my JScrollPane it works as desired.